# NetworkReader deserializes string into nonsense

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, serialization, deserialization

I'm working on writing a custom network message class that inherits from *MessageBase*, overriding its' *Serialize* and *Deserialize* functions.

I would like to be able to send the IPAddress of the player in this message. To do so, I'm setting the *SpawnMessage.Address* property to the *client.connection.address* from an outside class (both are string types).

However, when I Serialize -> Send -> Deserialize this message, I'm getting nonsense strings from my NetworkReader for the ipaddress when I'm expecting "localServer" in this particular example.

Where am I going wrong? And is there potentially a better way of doing this?

```
public class LineObjectMessage : MessageBase
{   
    public LineSpawn SpawnMessage = new LineSpawn();

    public override void Serialize(NetworkWriter writer)
    {
        writer.StartMessage(NetworkMessageTypes.LineObjectSpawnMessage);

        writer.Write(SpawnMessage.IpAddress);
        writer.Write(SpawnMessage.NetId);
        writer.Write(SpawnMessage.Thickness);

        writer.FinishMessage();
    }

    public override void Deserialize(NetworkReader reader)
    {
        SpawnMessage = new LineSpawn();

        SpawnMessage.IpAddress = reader.ReadString();
        SpawnMessage.NetId = reader.ReadNetworkId();
        SpawnMessage.Thickness = reader.ReadDouble(); 
    }

    [Serializable]
    public partial class LineSpawn
    {
        public string IpAddress;

        public double Thickness;

        public NetworkInstanceId NetId;
    }       
}
```

[image]

Comment: You might have to [encode/decode to/from base64 string](http://answers.unity.com/answers/40579/view.html)?

Comment: No luck. Moving *SpawnMessage.IpAddress = reader.ReadString();* to be read last instead of first throws a "string too long" error as well. It's almost as if the offset is wrong or something.